# Как поменять изображения предприятия?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Вопрос в области SEO и знаний оптимизаций кода. Есть определенная компания, которая продвигает свою продукцию в сети, и которая легко находится в сети по поиску. В прошлом, поисковик взял картинки, и сейчас надо обновить фотографии. 
Как сообщить гуглу об обновлении изображений касательно предприятия (картинки и карта)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте руководство **[Справка Гугл Мой Бизнес Как управлять данными о компании прямо в Google](https://support.google.com/business/answer/7039811)**:

Если вы вошли в аккаунт сервиса "Google Мой бизнес", то можете управлять данными о компании прямо в Google Поиске. Для этого нужно лишь найти их в Google и внести необходимые изменения: добавить или исправить информацию, опубликовать фотографии или записи, просмотреть отзывы клиентов и т. п.

Вот как управлять данными о компании в Google Поиске:

> Убедитесь, что вы вошли в аккаунт Google Мой бизнес.
>
> Найдите свою компанию в Google. Над результатами поиска вы увидите простое меню.
>
> ... Нажмите Добавить фото, чтобы поделиться фотографиями, которые помогут привлечь покупателей.
>
> Эту панель видят только владельцы и администраторы страницы компании.